# How can I get the "purpose" (Client Authentication Certificate) of a certificate in .NET?

Tags: .net, authentication, ssl, certificate, client-certificates

I want to find all client authentication certificates from the `X509Store(StoreLocation.CurrentUser)`

Is there anyway to do this? Even by getting all then filtering by a certain property to get all Client Authentication certificates?

Answer (score 2):

There are extensions that help identifying what can be used as client-certificate:

- The [Extended Key Usage extension](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.12), which will be `id-kp-clientAuth` if present.
- The "legacy" Netscape Cert Type extension (not strictly standard, but widely adopted, even outside the world of Netscape/Mozilla tools).

Certificates without these extensions at all could also be used as client-certificate, provided it's compatible with the [(non-extended) Key Usage extension](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4.2.1.3) (if present). What you need at least in the (non-extended) Key Usage extension is `digitalSignature` for a client-certificate. It's not really clear what happens if you get both the Netscape Cert Type and the Extended Key Usage extensions, although, in the spirit of RFC 5280, it would be worth considering usage for purposes compatible with all the extensions present:

> If a certificate contains both a key
> usage extension and an extended    key
> usage extension, then both extensions
> MUST be processed    independently and
> the certificate MUST only be used for
> a purpose    consistent with both
> extensions.  If there is no purpose
> consistent    with both extensions,
> then the certificate MUST NOT be used
> for any    purpose.

The [NSS Technical Note 3 (All About Certificate Extensions)](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/security/pki/nss/tech-notes/tn3.html) should be of interest.

Comment: I forgot to add that you also need to check the extension value required in the CA certificates in the chain (see NSS tech note).

Comment: Can I configure TLS handshake to request only certificates with specific usage (Client Authentication), instead of all of the certificates they've got installed?

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to examine the [Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.extensions.aspx) of each certificate. So far as I can see, once you've got to the [Key Usage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509keyusageextension.aspx) extension, you should have all the info you need.

*Edit* Actually, for client authentication, you probably need the Enhanced Key Usage extension. I don't have a client authentication certificate lying around to test this with, but the following prints "Server Authentication" for a server certificate I've got:

```
        var cert1 = new X509Certificate2(/* Path to certificate */);
        foreach (var ext in cert1.Extensions)
        {
            var eku = ext as X509EnhancedKeyUsageExtension;
            if (eku != null)
            {
                foreach (var oid in eku.EnhancedKeyUsages)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(oid.FriendlyName);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: I've one user auth cert installed and for that I went through all .Extensions and non of them looks actually useful for this purpose. Also non of them in the X509EnhancedKeyUsageExtension type

Comment: @dr. evil - I just generated a client auth certificate using our test CA (standard windows CA), and the code printed "Client Authentication". If your certificate doesn't have an EnhancedKeyUsage extension, what extensions does it have? (my Client Auth certificate also had the X509KeyUsageExtension, with DataEncipherment, KeyEncipherment, NonRepudiation, DigitalSignature)

Comment: It has 1-X509BasicConstraintsExtension, 3-X509Extension ("Netscape comment", "Subject Key Identifier","Auth Key")